# Get Source of XmlSerializer FormatException?

Tags: xmlserializer, formatexception

i'm deserializing some XML Data i get from a WebService using the XmlSerialzier. This worked quite good until now, but since some days i get an FormatException while the Serializer parses the XML.

Is there any Chance to get the Value/Element/Tagname the Serialzer tried to parse when the Exeption was thrown? I haven't found anything in the Exception Details.

Thanks and Greetings

Kornelis

Answer (score 0):

If the format exception doesn't give you enough information to solve the problem, you can go one step further and debug the specific code that produces the problem. The XmlSerializer works by generating a assembly at runtime which is responsible for serializing/deserializing the type you want. This generated code can be debugged in the following way [(check link)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HOWTODebugIntoANETXmlSerializerGeneratedAssembly.aspx).